# jQuery reload page with POST or GET variables

Tags: jquery, variables, post, get

I have a javascript block which reloads the current url after an ajax request has been made. Sometimes the url to reload has GET variables and sometimes POST.

In the case of POST variables the following prompts the user to confirm re-submission of the form data:

```
window.location.reload();
```

So I switched to this which doesn't prompt:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

But the problem with the second solution is that in the absence of POST variables the page doesn't load!

I simply need to load the current URL whatever it might be - POST or GET. I do not care about the original value of any POST variables.

**Update:**

Another qustion, why does Chrome prompt me for re-submission of the form data, yet Forefox and Edge do?

Comment: You could write some jquery to check if post variables are present, and if so add a hidden form to the DOM and post it programatically. But you may want to reconsider the structure. The two condition: (1) my page only loads with POST variables and (2) I need to reload this page - don't seem compatable. Can you change this structure?

Comment: @arbuthnott It seems like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer if I re-structure. This it seems is a clear limitation of of jQuer because it is not possible to simply load the current url again without re-loading or refreshing. Makes no sense

Comment: I think the general idea of POST is that data is being submitted and the page is the response. You can use it other ways, but it works most naturally that way. As a result, browsers might warn you when you try to refresh a page fetched by POST (because you are resending the submitted data). Some good guidelines on use here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: But if you have to reload via post here, you really can programatically create a form and submit it in just a few lines. Do you have a way of telling (in the javascript) whether POST or GET is required?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the post/get is set or not before setting the value. Then it will continue the rest of the page.

You could use isset();

like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['yourPostVariable'])){
   $yourPostVar = $_POST['yourPostVariable']; 
} else {
   $yourPostVar = "";
}
```

Same with GET:

```
if(isset($_GET['yourGetVariable'])){
   $yourGetVar = $_GET['yourGetVariable']; 
} else {
   $yourGetVar = "";
}
```

If you do that with all your variables near the top of your code then it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this soltion which seems to work:

```
if(window.location.search){ // if the url to reload has GET vars in the url
     window.location.href = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
}

else{ // else we are delaing with a POST request
     window.location.href = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
}
```

Basically I am re-constructing the url which appears to call the page again without a re-loading of the POST vars.